# Error: Refresh failed because resolved configuration is not available

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, refreshapex

I am trying to clear the cache of my wire method. But I have added refreshApex in my code but I am getting error

> Error: Refresh failed because resolved configuration is not available.

My Code

```
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';

export default class LwcCaseCritical extends LightningElement {

caseCriticalControllerApex

/**
*   @description: Get case information On page load
*                 
*/
@wire(caseCriticalControllerApex, {caseid: '$recordId'})
    getcaseCriticalControllerApex({error, data}) {

        if (data) {

            console.log('inside case Critical ControllerApex ');

            this.caseCriticalControllerApex = data;
            __showComponentLoader(this, '.pageLoader');
            console.log('recordId ', this.recordId);
            this.cases = data;
            console.log('CriticalFlag ', this.cases.CriticalFlag__c);
            this.oldPriorityValue = this.cases.Priority;  
            this.caseObject.CriticalFlag__c = this.cases.CriticalFlag__c;
            this.caseObject.Priority = this.cases.Priority;
            __hideComponentLoader(this, '.pageLoader');

        } else if (error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

 /**
*   @description: On click of save button
*                 
*/    
save(){
    __showComponentLoader(this, '.pageLoader');

    //this.cases.Id = this.recordId;
    this.caseObject.Id = this.recordId;

    console.log('cases details ' , this.cases);
    console.log('caseObject details ' , this.caseObject);

    saveApex({newCase : this.cases, updatedCaseValuse :this.caseObject, 
             errorMessage : '', oldPriorityValue: this.oldPriorityValue})
        .then(result => {
            this.errorMesage = result;

            if(this.errorMesage !== null && this.errorMesage !== ''){
                __showNotification(this, 'Case',this.errorMesage, 'Error', '');
            }else if(this.errorMesage === null || this.errorMesage === ''){
                __showNotification(this, 'Case','Case Updated', 'Success', '');
                this.refreshConsolePage();

                if(this.isEsclation === true && this.is3rdLevelUser === false){
                    const clickedevt = new CustomEvent('savecomplete', {
                        detail: { close : true },
                    });        
                    // Fire the custom event
                    this.dispatchEvent(clickedevt);
                }else{
                    const clickedevt = new CustomEvent('savecomplete', {
                        detail: { close : false },
                    });        
                    // Fire the custom event
                    this.dispatchEvent(clickedevt);
                }
            }

            console.log('this.isEsclation  ' + this.isEsclation );
            console.log('this.is3rdLevelUser  ' + this.is3rdLevelUser );
            /*
            refreshApex(this.overrideCaseIfNeededApex); 
            refreshApex(this.showPriorityApex);
            refreshApex(this.caseCriticalControllerApex); 
            */ 
            __hideComponentLoader(this, '.pageLoader');
            return refreshApex(this.caseCriticalControllerApex); 
        })
        .catch(error =>{
            console.log('error data ::: ' , error);
        });
}

}
```

Do any one have nay idea why I am getting this error on click of button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `refreshApex to` work, you need to pass complete response, not just the `data` part.

```
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';

export default class LwcCaseCritical extends LightningElement {

caseCriticalControllerApex

backupResponseFromWire;


@wire(caseCriticalControllerApex, {caseid: '$recordId'})
    getcaseCriticalControllerApex(resp) {
        this.backupResponseFromWire = resp;
        var data = resp.data;
        var error = resp.error;
        if (data) {

            console.log('inside case Critical ControllerApex ');

            this.caseCriticalControllerApex = data;
            __showComponentLoader(this, '.pageLoader');
            console.log('recordId ', this.recordId);
            this.cases = data;
            console.log('CriticalFlag ', this.cases.CriticalFlag__c);
            this.oldPriorityValue = this.cases.Priority;  
            this.caseObject.CriticalFlag__c = this.cases.CriticalFlag__c;
            this.caseObject.Priority = this.cases.Priority;
            __hideComponentLoader(this, '.pageLoader');

        } else if (error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

and then in your save method

`return refreshApex(this.backupResponseFromWire);`

Comment: very close but missed very important things. Thanks for your help.